# Probability inequality for the case $E(X^2)=1$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I am trying to solve the following exercise from Kai Kai Chung's A Course in Probability Theory:

If $E(X^2)=1$ and $E(|X|)\ge a>0$ then $P[|X|\ge \lambda a]\ge (1-\lambda)^2 a^2$ for every $0\le \lambda \le 1$.

I know that the second condition implies that $a\le 1$ by Jensen's inequality and hence the proposition holds for trivial cases $\lambda \in \{0,1\}$. I guess I could integrate some indicator functions but I have no clue. Could someone give me a hint?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley%E2%80%93Zygmund_inequality

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to MSE!

Hint:

It's often useful to split up a random variable into the places where it is "good" and "bad". Then we can control those regions separately to get whatever inequality we're interested in.

For this, we might try looking at the decomposition

$$
X = 
X \cdot \mathbf{1}_{\{X \leq \lambda a\}} + X \cdot \mathbf{1}_{\{X > \lambda a\}}
$$

The expectation of the first term is at most $\lambda a$, more or less by definition.

The expectation of the second term is at most $\sqrt{E[X^2]} \cdot \sqrt{\Pr[X > \lambda a]}$ (do you see why?)

Do you see how to combine these facts in order to get the claim? If you get stuck, you might want to google the "Paley–Zygmund inequality".

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Answer (score 2):

You can write
$$
E(|X|1(|X|\geq \lambda a)) \leq \left(E(X^2) P(|X|\geq \lambda a)\right)^{1/2} = P^{1/2}(|X|\geq \lambda a)
$$
The first inequality is Cauchy-Schwarz. Then
$$
E(|X|1(|X|\geq \lambda a)) =E(|X|) - E(|X|1(|X|< \lambda a))\geq a-\lambda a.
$$

Combining the last two displays and using $\lambda\in (0,1)$
$$
P(|X|\geq \lambda a)\geq (1-\lambda)^2a^2.
$$